# Matplotlib axis position and colorbar alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to align multiple colorbars with subplots generated with either `gridspec` or `fig.add_subplots`. I'd like to add the colorbar with `fig.add_axes` in matplotlib (v2.02), because it allows detailed alignment control. However, I need to get the figure position in order to do the alignment. The `ax.get_position()` function does not appear to return the correct coordinates:

Here is an MWE:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import scipy.misc

fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
lena = scipy.misc.face()
im = ax.imshow(lena)
axpos = ax.get_position() # bbox# get_position().get_points()
cbar_axis = fig.add_axes([axpos.x0, axpos.y0-0.1, axpos.width, 0.05])
colorbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_axis, orientation="horizontal")
```

The colorbar does not align:
[image: image with misaligned colorbar]

If I print `axpos` after the code runs, and `ax.get_position()`, the two are not the same. This suggests that `ax.get_position()` is using stale information while the code is executing. I've tried adding `plt.show()` and `plt.draw()` and it does not fix this.

How can I get the axis position?

**EDIT**:

I've modified the solution posted below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731797/238882) to better show what I am trying to do and why `make_axes_locatable` does not appear (yet) to work for me. I want two colorbars under one column, and one under another column. Doing this with `make_axes_locatable` and the following code produces the figure below. I would like the figures to all remain equal sizes and aligned in a grid.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import scipy.misc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

plt.close(1)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)

lena = scipy.misc.face()

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):

    im = ax.imshow(lena)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    if i == 2:
        ax_cb = divider.new_vertical(size="10%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")
        ax_cb2 = divider.new_vertical(size="10%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb2)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb2,  orientation="horizontal")
    if i == 3:
        ax_cb = divider.new_vertical(size="10%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't want to use the absolute positions of the axes, because this might (as you found out) change depending on other artists drawn or the figure placed in a canvas.

If the aim is to position the colorbar below the axes, a useful way is to use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable` as seen in [this official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_divider.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import scipy.misc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
lena = scipy.misc.face()
im = ax.imshow(lena)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

ax_cb = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
fig.add_axes(ax_cb)

fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this is absolutely compatible with `tight_layout` while setting an axes with `add_axes` is not.

You may create further errorbars by dividing the axes further using a second call to `divider.new_vertical`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import scipy.misc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)

lena = scipy.misc.face()

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):

    im = ax.imshow(lena)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax_cb = divider.new_vertical(size="10%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
    ax_cb2 = divider.new_vertical(size="10%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
    fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")
    if i % 2 - 1:
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb2)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb2,  orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit for the edited part of the question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import scipy.misc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)

lena = scipy.misc.face()

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):

    im = ax.imshow(lena)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax_cb = divider.new_vertical(size="8%", pad=0.3, pack_start=True)
    ax_cb2 = divider.new_vertical(size="8%", pad=0.02, pack_start=True)
    if i == 2:
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb2)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb2,  orientation="horizontal")
        ax_cb.tick_params(bottom=False,labelbottom=False)
    if i == 3:
        fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cb,  orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a second colorbar below the first? And keep the four images (only one shown in this MWE) all the same size as each other?

Comment: Do you want to have 2 colorbars for each of the four images then? Are the images the same size?

Comment: Yes all four images the same size, and I'm trying to have 2 colorbars under the left column, and 1 under the right.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to not be specific enough in the original question. I've updated it to better reflect what I'm trying to do (thanks to your code). I'm also preferential to `fig.add_axes` because it allows things like this: http://imgur.com/eESKR8p which I don't know how to do with `make_axes_locatable`.

Comment: Although I think that my previous solution shows already how to make the plots the same size, I updated the answer with the specific code to achieve the request from the edited question.

Comment: Got it. I was adding too many `divider` calls. This is very helpful. Thank you for all the assistance despite my changing requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically get a suitable `pad` value for the colorbar? For instance, use a smaller padding if the axis label is not shown, a larger one otherwise?