# How do I add a colorbar to a figure with multiple subplots?

Tags: matplotlib

Trying to add a colorbar to the right of the following plot:
[image: without_colorbar]

When adding a colorbar, the rightmost plot becomes very small:
[image]

I have tried changing the ratios of the gridspec to no avail.
I'd like main plot, right plot and colorbar to have the same height.
Here's the code I have been using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0xBEEF)
matrix = np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 10))

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gridspec = figure.add_gridspec(2, 2, width_ratios=(7, 1), height_ratios=(1, 7))

main_axes = figure.add_subplot(gridspec[1, 0])
main_plot = main_axes.imshow(matrix)

right_axes = figure.add_subplot(gridspec[1, 1])
right_axes.imshow(matrix[:, 0:1])
right_axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
right_axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

top_axes = figure.add_subplot(gridspec[0, 0])
top_axes.imshow(matrix[0:1, :])
top_axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
top_axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# figure.colorbar(main_plot, ax=right_axes, fraction=1)  # uncomment this line

plt.show()
```

Comment: fraction is an argument that indicates how much of the specified Axes should be used for the color bar. I found the number 1.63 by trial and error.

Comment: Using 1.63 as the fraction argument, the colorbar is drawn on top of the right plot for me. Do you have a working example?

Comment: My example also overlapped with the color bar, but I am posting it at that time because I think I need to adjust the position of the color bar.

Comment: [Matplotlib axis position and colorbar alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729133/matplotlib-axis-position-and-colorbar-alignment/44731797#44731797)